# pg_xlog files not recycling on slave

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, database-replication

I've setup streaming replication with postgres 9.3
My problem is that on the Slave server the pg_xlog folder just gets fuller and fuller and WAL files are not getting recycled.

The slave server has the following (relevant) values in postgresql.conf on slave server:

```
wal_keep_segments = 150
hot_standby = on
checkpoint_segments = 32
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
archive_mode = off
#archive_command = ''
```

My initial replication command was:

```
pg_basebackup  --xlog-method=stream -h <master-ip> -D .  --username=replication --password
```

So I guess my WAL files are OK.
Here is my slave server startup log:

```
2017-05-08 09:55:31 IDT LOG:  database system was shut down in recovery at 2017-05-08 09:55:19 IDT
2017-05-08 09:55:31 IDT LOG:  entering standby mode
2017-05-08 09:55:31 IDT LOG:  redo starts at 361/C76DD3E8
2017-05-08 09:55:31 IDT LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 361/C89A8278
2017-05-08 09:55:31 IDT LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
2017-05-08 09:55:31 IDT LOG:  record with zero length at 361/C89A8278
2017-05-08 09:55:31 IDT LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 361/C8000000 on timeline 1
2017-05-08 09:55:32 IDT LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2017-05-08 09:58:34 IDT LOG:  received SIGHUP, reloading configuration files
2017-05-08 09:58:34 IDT LOG:  parameter "checkpoint_completion_target" changed to "0.9"
```

I even tried to copy older WAL files from master server manually to slave but that also didn't help.
What am I doing wrong? How can I stop the pg_xlog folder from growing indefinitely?
Is it related to the "incomplete startup packet" log message?

one last thing: under the pg_xlog\archive_status folder all of the WAL files are with .done suffix.

Appreciate any help I can get on this.

### Edit:

I enabled log_checkpoints in postgresql.conf.
Here are the relevant log entries since I enabled it:

```
2017-05-12 08:43:11 IDT LOG:  parameter "log_checkpoints" changed to "on"
2017-05-12 08:43:24 IDT LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 2128 buffers (0.9%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 9 recycled; write=189.240 s, sync=0.167 s, total=189.549 s; sync files=745, longest=0.010 s, average=0.000 s
2017-05-12 08:45:15 IDT LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2017-05-12 08:48:46 IDT LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 15175 buffers (6.6%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=209.078 s, sync=1.454 s, total=210.617 s; sync files=769, longest=0.032 s, average=0.001 s
2017-05-12 08:50:15 IDT LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2017-05-12 08:53:45 IDT LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 2480 buffers (1.1%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=209.162 s, sync=0.991 s, total=210.253 s; sync files=663, longest=0.076 s, average=0.001 s
```

### Edit2:

Following the fact that my slave server has no restart points in the log, here is the relevant log for starting and recovering WALS in slave server before achieving consistent recovery state:

```
2017-05-12 09:35:42 IDT LOG:  database system was shut down in recovery at 2017-05-12 09:35:41 IDT
2017-05-12 09:35:42 IDT LOG:  entering standby mode
2017-05-12 09:35:42 IDT LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2017-05-12 09:35:43 IDT FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2017-05-12 09:35:43 IDT LOG:  restored log file "0000000100000369000000B1" from archive
2017-05-12 09:35:43 IDT FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2017-05-12 09:35:44 IDT FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2017-05-12 09:35:44 IDT LOG:  restored log file "0000000100000369000000AF" from archive
2017-05-12 09:35:44 IDT LOG:  redo starts at 369/AFD28900
2017-05-12 09:35:44 IDT FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2017-05-12 09:35:45 IDT FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2017-05-12 09:35:45 IDT FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2017-05-12 09:35:46 IDT LOG:  restored log file "0000000100000369000000B0" from archive
2017-05-12 09:35:46 IDT FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2017-05-12 09:35:46 IDT FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2017-05-12 09:35:47 IDT FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2017-05-12 09:35:47 IDT LOG:  restored log file "0000000100000369000000B1" from archive
2017-05-12 09:35:47 IDT FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2017-05-12 09:35:48 IDT FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2017-05-12 09:35:48 IDT LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2017-05-12 09:35:49 IDT LOG:  restored log file "0000000100000369000000B2" from archive
2017-05-12 09:35:50 IDT LOG:  restored log file "0000000100000369000000B3" from archive
2017-05-12 09:35:52 IDT LOG:  restored log file "0000000100000369000000B4" from archive   
.
.
.
2017-05-12 09:42:33 IDT LOG:  restored log file "000000010000036A000000C0" from archive
2017-05-12 09:42:35 IDT LOG:  restored log file "000000010000036A000000C1" from archive
2017-05-12 09:42:36 IDT LOG:  restored log file "000000010000036A000000C2" from archive
2017-05-12 09:42:37 IDT LOG:  restored log file "000000010000036A000000C3" from archive
2017-05-12 09:42:37 IDT LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 36A/C3ACEB28
2017-05-12 09:42:37 IDT LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
2017-05-12 09:42:39 IDT LOG:  restored log file "000000010000036A000000C4" from archive
2017-05-12 09:42:40 IDT LOG:  restored log file "000000010000036A000000C5" from archive
2017-05-12 09:42:42 IDT LOG:  restored log file "000000010000036A000000C6" from archive
ERROR: WAL file '000000010000036A000000C7' not found in server 'main-db-server'
2017-05-12 09:42:42 IDT LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 36A/C6000000 on timeline 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is replication working (does a change to the primary appear on the standby)? What is `checkpoint_segments` on the standby? How many WAL files are in `pg_xlog` on the standby? The *incomplete startup packet* message is from a flawed connection attempt and has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: replication is working. checkpoint_segments on slave is 32. I have about 320 files right now in pg_xlog.

Comment: WAL files are recycled during restart points. Can you check if files are removed/renamed after a restart point or not?

Comment: Actually now the problem seems to have been resolved.
I had it yesterday, but then I deleted the salve pg_data folder and did the backup again with the --xlog-method=stream option and now files are rotating in pg_xlog - I should have been more patient before posting this question. Thanks!

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Now the problem is back - I have now 1436 wals in my slave pg_xlog server.
I tried to restart the db server but it doesn't seem to help.
I'm thinking the slave server can't get a valid restore point maybe? even though I am able to access the DB and perform queries on it, and I have almost no replication lag (a few seconds)

Comment: Anything in the logs on the master or the slave? I hope you are running 9.3.16 and not an old release. Do files get recycled? You could check by reading the log file with `tail -f` and wait for `restartpoint complete` messages. At the same time, observe `pg_xlog` with `watch -d --interval=1 ls -l pg_xlog \| head -10` and see if something changes when the restartpoint completes.

Comment: I'm pretty convinced that my backup is corrupted to some extent - as when I restart it restores all of the old WALs that is has saved in pg_xlog.
I've just set up a backup using barman on a separate server, I'm thinking of starting from a fresh pg_basebackup and use a restore command in my recovery.conf.
Main thing is - how can I really check if my slave data is corrupted? is there any way of doing this? When I query the DB everything seems fine and the DB starts up fine eventually.

Comment: If you restart the slave, recovery will start at the latest restore point. Please look into your PostgreSQL log file and see if there are `restartpoint starting` and `restartpoint complete` messages. I don't know if that query works with restart points, but what do you get for `SELECT checkpoint_time FROM pg_control_checkpoint();`?

Comment: pg_control_checkpoint() is not supported in postgres 9.3, and I could not find the words restartpoint in any of my logs :-\

Comment: I forgot to tell you that you have to set `log_checkpoints` to `on` to get these log entries.

Comment: That's the master - the interesting thing is what you see on the slave if you enable `log_checkpoints`.

Comment: I have it enabled in slave, and I did not see any logs for checkpoints on the slave. If i restart the slave DB it seems to recover a lot of wal files from the archive (about a Day and a half old) after an "incomplete startup packet message"

Comment: If you see no restartpoints in the log on the slave, that's the cause of the problem. Now we'll have to figure out why. Maybe you could post the log from a restart of the slave, when it is recovering lots of WAL (trim it down to the interesting lines). Wait until more then five minutes have passed after a consistent recovery state has been reached, so that there should be a restartpoint.

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe - I've added the relevant Log.
The last file (000000010000036A000000C7) wasn't found in the archive because it was still in the master and was not yet archived.

Comment: What do you get for `SELECT pg_is_in_backup()` on the master? It almost looks like the backup never finished...

Comment: I get f (false) - and I have daily backups which are working (starting and finishing) every night. I also want to note that if I restore slave from backup, and set it up again - WALs are rotating for about 24-48 hours before the issue starts again - so maybe this is happening because of heavy loads at some point?

Comment: I restored the slave from backup. now WALs are recycling and I see restart points being made. I will wait and see if wal folder starts growing again I will now probably have a relevant log on my slave server.

Comment: That is great! I hope we can solve this problem.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - I've managed to solve the problem. I added an answer with details. Thanks for all your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to have been resolved.

Apparently I had hardware issues on the master server.
I was able to perform full pg_dump and re-index my DB so I was *pretty sure* I did not have any data integrity issues.

But when looking at the master server logs after I've enabled log_checkpoints in the config - a few minutes before the slave server stopped performing checkpoints I saw the following message:

```
IDT ERROR:  failed to re-find parent key in index "<table_name>_id_udx" for split pages 17/18
```

After seeing that - I decided to switch hosting provider and moved my DB to a new server.
Since then (almost a week now) - everything has been running smoothly replication and checkpoints are running as expected.

I really hope this will help other people - but when something like this is happening - always be advised that this issue might be caused by data integrity/hardware issues.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. Lesson to be learned: always look at the log first. Did the master continue having checkpoints and only the slave didn't?

Comment: Yes. The master continue having checkpoints and only the slave didn't. And its not just about looking at the log.its about what to log as well :-)